# Is there a way to add a react-native component to Android app?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to develop a react-native component and need to use it both for android and IOS. I read [react-native integration-with-existing-apps](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) but here for Android they mentioned to add existing android project to the react-native project. is there any other way ? Can we add react-native component inside existing android project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, it states:

> To ensure a smooth experience, create a new folder for your integrated
>  React Native project, then copy your existing Android project to an
>  `/android` subfolder.

Which has another meaning: it is **not compulsory** to create a new folder for your integrated RN project, you can even have your react native file outside your project file.  In order to ensure the flow and ease, it is advisable you to put either android into react native project directory or react native into android directory (which is what you want).

Comment: is there any sample steps for adding react-native to android directory ?

Comment: Just put your RN file in android project, do the same steps as stated